# cannot load the TranslatorInterface in my formType

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, formbuilder

I try to introduce some translation into a `ChatBundle` in order to follow the changes of the `_locale` of the hosting app in `Symfony 4`.

So in the formBuilder i try to inject the `TranslatorInterface` as such:

```php
// lib/ChatBundle/Form/ChatMessageType.php

namespace bornToBeAlive\ChatBundle\Form;

use bornToBeAlive\ChatBundle\Entity\ChatMessage;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class ChatMessageType extends AbstractType
{
    private $trans;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $trans)
    {
        $this->trans = $trans;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('content', null, [
                'attr'=> ['placeholder' => $this->trans->trans('placeholder',[],'chat')]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ChatMessage::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

but when I try to run my `show` action:

```php
public function show(): Response
{
    $message = new ChatMessage();

    $form = $this->createForm(ChatMessageType::class, $message);

    return $this->render('@Chat/show.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

I get the following error :

> Too few arguments to function bornToBeAlive\ChatBundle\Form\ChatMessageType::__construct(), 0 passed in ../vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php on line 92 and exactly 1 expected

I'm surprised because I use this technique when I'm in my host app for the other type. did I do something wrong ?

Comment: What's the symfony version? Also - how do you use `ChatMessageType`?

Comment: are you sure ```Types```are supported for dependency injection, to my understanding to be autowired they have to be considered as Service which a Type doesn't seem to be to me.

Comment: I use it in all my `Types` in the hosting app and it work like a charm

Comment: with the same Interface? sorry, did you clear cache?

Comment: Show your code where you execute  ChatMessageType

Comment: I edited my question with the controller code

Comment: I think you need `new ChatMessageType(your translator)`;

Comment: I cannot use object as a first parameter in `createForm`

Comment: Try to install annotations with ```composer require annotations``` . this will install symfony framework extrabundle as well. It should solve your issue

Comment: it didn't change anything

Comment: What is your Symfony version?

Comment: Which version of symfony/translation is installed? Looks like the interface is in another namespace in the newer versions. Also see this issue https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/31152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Symfony 4.4 Form documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/form/create_custom_field_type.html#passing-variables-to-the-form-type-template) :

> If you're using the default **services.yaml** configuration, this example will already work! Otherwise, create a service for this form class and tag it with form.type.

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true 
        public: false
```

If autowiring is not working as expected, you can define form as service, like this

```
# config/services.yaml
app.form.corporation_type:
    class: bornToBeAlive\ChatBundle\Entity\ChatMessageType
    arguments: ["@translator"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

Comment: And have a look to : https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-improved-form-translation

Comment: Effectively as I live in a separated bundle, I didn't set the `autowire` option. I needed to declare the service manually.